# Switch Statement and If Statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, switch-statement

Why switch case does not take multiple lines
where if do work perfectly

```
if(indexPath.row == 1){
            UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
            viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            viewController.title = _titlesArray[indexPath.row];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControlleranimated:YES];
}
```

same code unable to use in switch case statement

```
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
                    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    viewController.title = _titlesArray[indexPath.row];
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControlleranimated:YES];
    break;
                    case 1:
                    break;

                    default
                     break:
}
```

In switch statement its gives an errors....
I forcibly using if else statement instated of switch case.
Can any one advice me how use switch case statment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch will take multiple lines so long as there are no variable definitions. Any new definitions need to be enclosed. So, these are both valid:

```
case 0:
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewController.title = _titlesArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControlleranimated:YES];
break;
}
```

and

```
UIViewController *viewController;

...

case 0:
    viewController = [UIViewController new];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewController.title = _titlesArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControlleranimated:YES];
break;
```